# How to show a win32 application on logonUI by c#?

Tags: c#, windows, authentication

I write a sample calculator and show on logonUI.

Users can use it without login.

I don' know how to implement it.

Does anyone have similar experiences?

Comment: What information do the users use to login?  How do you validate that the login information is correct?  At this time this question is way to vague and broad to be answered in a meaningful way.

Comment: You can't do that, for security reasons. What if someone made a program that looked like the login screen, but actually collected everyone's passwords?

Comment: Thanks for your apply.
The similar sample is credential provider, that is a custom login experience.
So it can do technically.
But the calculator don't manage any login information.